# How to sort a query by a row and add multiple columns

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm making a query to get these results:

```
Concept  | Variety 1  | Variety 2 | Variety 3
-------- | ---------- | --------- | ---------
Stage 1  |   125.23   |  142.32   |  154.00
State 2  |   100.00   |  100.00   |  100.00
```

I have 2 DB's to get these results, and this query gives me this result

Query:

```sql
SELECT A.Etapa as CEtapa
     , Sum(P.Import) + Sum(P.HExtras) + Sum(P.Importunidades) as Total 
FROM Percepciones as P
   , [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Lotes as L
   , [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Actividades as A 
WHERE P.Apl2__ =  L.Numero 
AND P.Apl3__ = A.Numero
GROUP BY A.Etapa
ORDER BY A.Etapa
```

Result:

```sql
Concept  | Variety 1  
-------- | ---------- 
Stage 1  |   125.23   
State 2  |   100.00
```

The problem is that I have N amount of varieties and I need the query to do that, I'm using .NET to show these results. So I thought, "Why not just create a loop to add every variety." But, the problem that I'm having is that they're not getting calculated by stage, this is my test query:

```sql
SELECT A.Etapa as CEtapa
    ,(SELECT Total 
      FROM (SELECT Sum(P.Import) + Sum(P.HExtras) + Sum(P.Importunidades) as Total 
            FROM Percepciones as P
               , [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Lotes as L
               , [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Actividades as A 
            WHERE L.Numero = P.Apl2__
            AND Variedad = L.Variedad
            AND P.Apl3__ = A.Numero
        )
      ) as Variedad1 
FROM Percepciones as P
   , [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Lotes as L
   , [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Actividades as A 
WHERE P.Apl2__ =  L.Numero
AND P.Apl3__ = A.Numero 
GROUP BY A.Etapa
```

What I would loop on .Net to concatenate would be:

```sql
SELECT Total
FROM (SELECT Sum(P.Import) + Sum(P.HExtras) + Sum(P.Importunidades) as Total
      FROM Percepciones as P
         , [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Lotes as L
         , [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Actividades as A
      WHERE L.Numero = P.Apl2__ 
      AND Variedad = L.Variedad
      AND P.Apl3__ = A.Numero
     )
 ) as Variedad1
```

Sadly this gives me the same result on every stage because I'm not comparing the stage on the WHERE clause, because I don't know how to use the stage from the main query on the subquery.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm no expert, but this looks like a job for a pivot query.

Comment: Show sample raw data. Each stage can have multiple variety? CROSSTAB query needs 3 fields. Might need to use DCount() to generate a sequence id for each stage group. That calculated field would be the ColumnHeader.

Comment: @June7 Each stage can have n amount of varieties and there are n number of stages too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider MS Access SQL's unique [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) which wraps a `TRANSFORM` and `PIVOT` clause around an aggregate `GROUP BY` query to dynamically pivot aggregations across groupings.

Below groups by *Etapa* and pivots *Variedad* aggregating your calculated *Total* field. Do note the Access limit of N=255 columns in any query resultset. Also, below uses the explicit join with `INNER JOIN` (ANSI '92 standard of 25 years) as opposed to your use of the implicit join with comma-separated tables joined by `WHERE` clause. For multiple joins, Access SQL does require parentheses pairings.

```sql
TRANSFORM Sum(P.Import) + Sum(P.HExtras) + Sum(P.Importunidades) as Total
SELECT A.Etapa as CEtapa 
FROM (Percepciones as P
INNER JOIN [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Lotes as L
   ON P.[Apl2__] =  L.[Numero]) 
INNER JOIN [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Actividades as A 
   ON P.[Apl2__] =  A.[Numero]
GROUP BY A.Etapa
PIVOT L.Variedad
```

And should you want to limit the columns add `IN` to `PIVOT`:

```sql
PIVOT L.Variedad IN ('Variety 1', 'Variety 3', 'Variety 5')
```

Comment: There are (n) numbers of varieties and stages, i managed to get this working with this:
`SELECT etapa, SUM(iif(variedad=1,p.import + p.importunidades + p.hextras,0)), SUM(iif(variedad=2,p.import + p.importunidades + p.hextras,0)) 
FROM percepciones AS P, [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Lotes AS L, [\SYS21\Camel\COSTOS.MDB].Actividades AS A 
WHERE l.numero =p.apl2__ and a.numero = p.apl3__ 
GROUP BY etapa`

I like your style tho, looks more professional but it didnt worked when i tried to run it.

Comment: That is the other way to pivot data workable across RDBMS's (crosstab only allowed in Access). And you are still using implicit joins. What was the error as it should have worked without the `IN()` since as you show now *Variedad* is a number not string so use `IN(1, 2, ...)`.

Comment: The problem with trying to run your query was the query itself, i get a "JOIN expression not supported", im sorry for the delay on the answer but i would love to learn this way of doing it. Thank you!

Comment: Wow! I thought you were gone for good. I caught my issue in the second `ON` clause using `L` instead of `A` alias. See update. Unlike other pivot, crosstab does not require manual `SUM(IIF(...))` lines but runs across every value of column.

Comment: I see now how it works, it will be usefull as i've done this several times and i was always looking for a way to not loop the `SUM(IIf...` in code, thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent! Glad you finally got it to work. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks!, i got my own queries working with this now :)